# MPI_Send/Recv of std::vector not matching

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I don't understand why this code prints 0 instead of 1 on the received vector, am i doing something wrong?
Communication is working but it just prints five zeros instead of four zeros and a one.

```
int main(int arg, char** argvs) {
    int rank, numOfProcess;
    MPI_Init(&arg, &argvs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numOfProcess);
    MPI_Status status;
    if (rank == 0) {
        vector<int> prova(5);
        prova.push_back(1);
        MPI_Send(prova.data(), 5, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if (rank == 1) {
        vector<int> rec(5);
        MPI_Recv(rec.data(), 5, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        cout << rec.back() << endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The vector you're sending has 6 values (5 zeros followed by a 1) but you only send/receive the first 5 values (just the zeros). `vector<int> prova(4);` will fix it

Comment: Thanks, what a silly mistake i should go back and study more carefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your push_back is increasing the length of the vector by one. Thus, you are communicating a two small vector.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int arg, char** argvs) {
    int rank, numOfProcess;
    MPI_Init(&arg, &argvs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numOfProcess);
    MPI_Status status;
    if (rank == 0) {
        std::vector<int> prova(5);
        prova.push_back(1);
        MPI_Send(prova.data(), 6, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if (rank == 1) {
        std::vector<int> rec(6);
        MPI_Recv(rec.data(), 6, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        cout << rec.back() << endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```